# Python: First In First Out Print

Tags: python, lifo

I'm a beginner in python and I'm having an issue with this program:

The program below is a Last In First Out (LIFO). I want to make it First in First Out (FIFO) Program.

```
from NodeList import Node

class QueueLL:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None


    def enqueueQLL(self,item):
        temp = Node(str(item))
        temp.setNext(self.head) 
        self.head = temp
        length = max(len(node.data) for node in self.allNodes()) if self.head else 0
        print('\u2510{}\u250c'.format(' '*length))
        for node in self.allNodes():
            print('\u2502{:<{}}\u2502'.format(node.data, length))
        print('\u2514{}\u2518'.format('\u2500'*length))
```

Here is the NodeList:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext
```

NOTE: The "Rainbow" should be at the bottom of "Arc" or in FIFO (pic below is LIFO)

[image]

I'm thinking to put a new def like setPrevious in the NodeList But I dont know how. (to be honest I'm really new on these self.head = none stuffs . I used to write self.items = [])

Any help and tips will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

Apart from learning purposes I would not advise using a custom data structure for making a LIFO or FIFO. The built in data-type `list` is just fine after all.

You can add items using the `append` method and remove them using `pop`. For a LIFO this would look like this:

```
stack = list()
stack.append(1)
stack.append(2)
stack.append(3)

print stack.pop()  #3
print stack.pop()  #2
print stack.pop()  #1
```

If you supply an integer argument for `pop` you can specify which element to remove. For a FIFO use the index `0` for the first element:

```
stack = list()
stack.append(1)
stack.append(2)
stack.append(3)

print stack.pop(0)  #1
print stack.pop(0)  #2
print stack.pop(0)  #3
```

Comment: I also want to use that built in data-type but I don't know how to convert it into LinkList.

Comment: why do you need a linked list?

Comment: I am required in our class to implement a queue (including other data structures types) using linklist.

Comment: `list` is fine for a stack since both `.append()` and `.pop()` are fast. However, it's not the best for a FIFO queue because `.pop(0)` is slow (it's complexity is not `O(1)`). Use `collections.deque` for FIFO.

Answer (score 1):

Well, seeing as your class is probably over now and you didn't mention your class (or that it had to be a linked list) in the question itself, I'll just tell you the built-in easy way to do it, for now, which is probably more pertinent to your current situation (and will help people who find your question).

```
import sys;
if sys.version_info[0]>2: #Just making sure the program works with both Python 2.x and 3.x
    from queue import Queue
else:
    from Queue import Queue

q=Queue()
q.put("first") #Put an item on the Queue.
q.put("second")
q.put("third")

while not q.empty(): #If it's empty, the program will stall if you try to get from it (that's why we're checking)
    print(q.get()) #Get an item from the Queue
```

This outputs

```
first
second
third
```

Really, though, I'm not sure what advantages this has over Constantinius's answer, but since it's an included module, I would think there must be an advantage somewhere. I know they are used with threads from the threading module. There are more functions associated with Queues than I've mentioned here.

To learn more, open your Python interpreter and type this:

```
from queue import Queue #or from Queue import Queue for 2.x
help(Queue) #Press q to exit the help
```

Don't ask me what blocking is, but this *may* use the term how it's used in the Queue class documentation:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28computing%29)

Comment: Queue type is thread-save which the list type is not (that's why a Queue can block). Creating, filling and emptying a list in a fifo manner is more than 30 times faster here than doing the same with a Queue.  Thus if you don't need thread-savety ...

Answer (score 0):

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None        
class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None        
    def add(self,item):                
        temp=Box(item)                
        if self.head==None:
            self.head=temp
            self.prev=temp
        self.prev.next=temp
        self.prev=self.prev.next               
    def PrintList(self):
        while self.head!=None:
            print(self.head.data)
            self.head=self.head.next

myList=List()
myList.add("Vinoth")
myList.add("Karthick")
myList.add("Ganesh")
myList.add("Malai")
myList.add("Shan")
myList.add("Saravana")
myList.PrintList()
```